# check that all edittext is filled and display alert message

Tags: android

I have 9 edittext. Each edittext is in the form of a square. I look if all edittext has values, then an alert message is displayed without click of any button.

I tried with this code but it does not run.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
 public int Summ(int x, int y, int z) {
    int sum = 0;

sum = x + y + z;
    return sum;
}
 private void alertDialogLost()
{
    int a= Integer.parseInt(et1.getText().toString());
    int b = Integer.parseInt(et2.getText().toString());
    int c = Integer.parseInt(et3.getText().toString());



    int d = Integer.parseInt(et4.getText().toString());
    int e = Integer.parseInt(et5.getText().toString());
    int f = Integer.parseInt(et6.getText().toString());


    int g = Integer.parseInt(et7.getText().toString());
    int h = Integer.parseInt(et8.getText().toString());
    int k = Integer.parseInt(et9.getText().toString());
    if ((Summ(a,b,c)== Solution)&&(Summ(d,e,f)== Solution)&&(Summ(g,h,k)==Solution)&&
            (Summ(a,d,g)==Solution)&&(Summ(b,e,h)== Solution)&&(Summ(c,f,k)==Solution)
            &&(Summ(a,e,k)==Solution)&&(Summ(c,e,g)==Solution))

    {

        AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        View view1 = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this).inflate(R.layout.alertdiag, null);
        TextView title = (TextView) view1.findViewById(R.id.title);
        TextView message = (TextView) view1.findViewById(R.id.message);
        ImageView icone = (ImageView) view1.findViewById(R.id.icone);

        title.setText("Result");
        icone.setImageResource(R.drawable.smilega);
        message.setText("you have winner");

        builder1.setPositiveButton("contenue", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Main2Activity.class);

                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        });

        builder1.setView(view1);
        builder1.setCancelable(false);
        AlertDialog alertDialog1 = builder1.create();
        alertDialog1.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no code that checks if there are values. Not for one edittext. You could shkw how you would do it for one.

Comment: What is the value of `Solution` ?

Comment: Please tell which values for a,b,c,....k will pass the comparison.

Comment: thinks Solution=15

Comment: So they are all 5.

Comment: So add a TextWatcher to every EditText.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to show an `AlertDialog` the moment all nine `EditText` fields have values in them, using a `TextWatcher` would probably do the trick.

First, let's start with making things easier on ourselves. We'll add each `EditText` to an `ArrayList`, so we can iterate through them with a `forEach` loop:

```
List<EditText> editTextArrayList= new ArrayList<>();;
editTextArrayList.add(et1);
editTextArrayList.add(et2);
editTextArrayList.add(et3);

editTextArrayList.add(et4);
editTextArrayList.add(et5);
editTextArrayList.add(et6);

editTextArrayList.add(et7);
editTextArrayList.add(et8);
editTextArrayList.add(et9);
```

Then, let's set up a method to iterate through all nine `EditText` fields, checking if each one has a value. If any of them do not, the AlertDialog will not show:

```
private void checkAllEditTexts() {
    boolean allFilled = true;
    for (EditText editText : editTextArrayList) {
        if (editText.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
            allFilled = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (allFilled) {
        // show your AlertDialog
    }

}
```

Then we set up our `TextWatcher`, which will call the `checkAllEditTexts()` method if any text is changed on the `EditText` fields we'll be assigning it to:

```
private TextWatcher textWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        checkAllEditTexts();
    }
};
```

And finally, just below where we added the `EditText` fields to the `ArrayList`, we set up a `forEach` loop to add the `TextWatcher`:

```
List<EditText> editTextArrayList= new ArrayList<>();;
editTextArrayList.add(et1);
editTextArrayList.add(et2);
editTextArrayList.add(et3);

editTextArrayList.add(et4);
editTextArrayList.add(et5);
editTextArrayList.add(et6);

editTextArrayList.add(et7);
editTextArrayList.add(et8);
editTextArrayList.add(et9);

for (EditText editText : editTextArrayList) {
    editText.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
}
```

...and that should display your `AlertDialog` as soon as all nine text fields have a value.

Comment: No problem! Did it resolve your issue? Please mark it if so! :)

Comment: Good to hear it! Could you mark my answer as the correct one with the green checkmark? That way others will know that it worked for you. Thanks!